# Get the latest date in a document and output the line containing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, date, mongoose

I have a document called Application.txt with multiple columns and rows like so

`ApplNo DocsURL DocDate
 4782   www….   7/28/2003
 4782   www….   11/23/2008
 4782   www….   3/24/2012
 5010   www….   4/5/2003
 5010   www….   3/16/2008
 5010   www….   3/12/2013
 6002   www….   6/29/2009
 6002   www….   4/20/2011`

I need to find the latest Doc Date for each ApplNo value and save that entire row to a txt file. So for example, my code should go through the document and return this output to a text file

`ApplNo DocsURL DocDate
 4782   www….   3/24/2012
 5010   www….   3/12/2013
 6002   www….   4/20/2011`

I'm currently doing this to read the lines in my document

```
var dataFilename = config.file_path + '/datafiles/Application.txt';
console.log("Input file = " + dataFilename);
fs.createReadStream(dataFilename).pipe(parser);
```

However, I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm just starting with node js.

I did some research and saw that mongoose js would be a good option, using something like this

```
var Object = new Schema({
    ApplNo: Number
  , DocsURL: String
  , DocDate: Date
});

Object.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'created_at' : -1 } },function(err,post{
console.log( post );
});
```

But I'm not sure how to read my text document into the Schema or if this method will output the line containing the latest date for each Application Number.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does every line end with . ? May do string.split(".") or sth similar...

Comment: No the lines do not end with a period

Comment: what a beatiful text file. Would be easier to format it, just sayin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the whole string in file by line break into array .

Iterate this array and split each line into array using the multiple spaces.

Create an object where the app numbers are keys and compare dates storing appropriate data.

Then finally iterate the resultant object that contains the line with the highest date and do whatever you want with it

```js
var data = `ApplNo DocsURL DocDate
 4782   www….   7/28/2003
 4782   www….   11/23/2008
 4782   www….   3/24/2012
 5010   www….   4/5/2003
 5010   www….   3/16/2008
 5010   www….   3/12/2013
 6002   www….   6/29/2009
 6002   www….   4/20/2011`;

// create array from each line
var lines = data.split('\n');
// remove heading line
lines.splice(0, 1);
// object to store current highest date and line
var appObj = lines.reduce(function(a, c, i) {
  // remove extra whitespace and `\r`
  var line = c.trim(),
    // create array of columns for this line
    arr = line.split('   '),
    appNum = arr[0],
    date = new Date(arr[2]);
  if (!a[appNum]) {
    // if appNum not previously encountered, create new object
    a[appNum] = {line: line, date: date};
  } else if (date > a[appNum].date) {
    // or update existing appNum if greater date found
    a[appNum].date = date;
    a[appNum].line = line
  }
  return a;
}, {});


// iterate object and process results
Object.keys(appObj).forEach(function(appNum) {
  console.log('Line with high date for ', appNum, ' is ---- ', appObj[appNum].line)
})
```

Comment: @fluxing23 note that this is blocking. If youve got a really big txt file, this will take down your server...

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like nobodys answering this question i give it a try ( im quite new to nodejs too).
So it looks like we can get a String Stream like this:

```
var readable=fs.createReadStream(dataFilename);
readable.setEncoding("utf-8");
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  //chunk should be a part of a string
  console.log(chunk);
});
readable.on("end",()=>console.log("end"));
```

So now we need to store it somewhere, and split it by " " and group it by three:

```
var temp="";
var temparray=[];
var result=[];

var readable=fs.createReadStream(dataFilename);
readable.setEncoding("utf-8");
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  //append the chunk to our string:
  temp+=chunk;
  //get all completely transfered data
  var arr=temp.split(" ");
  //replace temp with the last elem:
  temp=arr.pop();
  //add the rest to our temp array:
  temparray=temparray.concat(arr);
  //get groups of three
  while(temparray.length>=3){
    result.push(temparray.splice(0,3));
  }
});
readable.on("end",()=>{
  console.log("not parsed:"+temp+";"+temparray.join(" "));
  result.forEach((row,line)=>console.log(line+":"+row.join(" "));
});
```

So result should now be an ordered array, sth like this:

```
var result=[
   ["5010", "www….", "3/12/2013"]
   ["6002",  "www….", "4/20/2011"]
];
```

Please check/comment and i will look further...

Comment: Thank you!! Knowing how to split my text file properly really helped.